# Present new word with each fadeIn with jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, fadein

How could I fix this problem? I have a word represented on the screen repeatedly with fadeIn.delay.fadeOut. If I pick this word randomly from an array, it does not exactly behave as I want.

I want to have the word, fade it out, and have the new word faded in. Now, it appears that the 'word change' happens too soon, see [example on fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8VHR5/)

Code:

```
var words = ["A", "B", "C", "D"];
var showwords = function() {
var newword = words[Math.floor((Math.random() * words.length))]
$("#words").text(newword)
            .fadeIn(50)
            .delay(2000)
            .fadeOut(500);
}
setInterval(showwords, 2000)
```

Can anyone help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/8VHR5/3/

I don't think your original code was queueing the fadeout, delay, and then fadein properly. Try it like this using the callback function of fadeOut so that the next bit of code only executes after that has completed.

```
var words = ["A", "B", "C", "D"];
var showwords = function() {
    var newword = words[Math.floor((Math.random() * words.length))]
    $("#words").fadeOut( 1000, function() {
         $("#words").text(newword).fadeIn(1000);
    });
}
setInterval(showwords, 3000)
```

Comment: Damn it, too slow! Exact same solution.  
I also tried `.fadeOut(t).delay(t).text(n).fadeIn(t)` but that didn't work right off the bat. Might be worth a shot though.

Comment: This works perfectly. One question though: how long is the letter visible each time? Exactly 1000ms? Because I need it presented for 2secs and and a period of 500ms where no letter is shown.

Comment: In the code above, 3000 is the total time. There is a fade in for 1000 and a fade out for 1000 which means the letter is shown for 3000-1000-1000=1000.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

```
setInterval(showwords, 2000)
```

put an amount equal or greater than 2550 (50 + 2000 + 500)

```
setInterval(showwords, 2600)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
 var words = ["A", "B", "C", "D"];
 var showwords = function() {
 var newword = words[Math.floor((Math.random() * words.length))]
 $("#words").text(newword)
            .fadeIn(1000)
            .fadeOut(1000);
}
setInterval(showwords, 2000)
```

http://jsfiddle.net/8VHR5/1/

Answer (score 0):

You want to leverage the callback function and think about it a little differently:

```
function showWords(){
    var newWord = words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)];

    $('#words').fadeOut(500,function(){
        $(this).text(newWord).fadeIn(500);

        setTimeout(showWords,2000);
    });

}
```

Notice the use of `setTimeout` instead of `setInterval`, as you have a recursive function called.